# Why is RegExp.prototype undefined?

Tags: javascript, regex, prototype

Why is RegExp.prototype undefined while it has methods and properties and it is an object?

```
console.log(RegExp.prototype); //undefined
typeof RegExp.prototype; //"object"
```

Comment: It is not undefined. console.log() will always return undefined. try just typing RegExp.prototype in your console.

Comment: @JohnSnow RegExp.prototype also returns undefined but it is clickable and like an object

Comment: You need to look into the difference between the "return" value of a function (which is always undefined unless explicitly specified) and the side effects that it can perform (like logging to the console).

Comment: @JohnSnow Thanks...but why is undefined displayed when i type RegExp.prototype; in console?

Comment: It is not. Open your developer console and write RegExp.prototype. Do not write console.log(RegExp.prototype). And you're welcome.

Comment: @JohnSnow I do so without console.log()..undefined is displayed and when i click on it,properties and method are displayed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194395/discussion-between-zahra19977-and-johnsnow).

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get `Object { ... }`.

Comment: @melpomene I dont know why firefox displays undefined.

Comment: I'm using Firefox. I get `Object { ... }`.